# JMETER - Getting SSL Handshake Fatal Error while recording script

Tags: ssl, jmeter

i just need to consult u if u have any idea. I am load testing a Banks application using JMETER. They have hosted that app. on LAN. We cannot open anything on LAN except the banks app, not even Google bcoz of tight security. Everything is Blocked except Banks App. Now when i try record the script using jmeter, Bank App doesnt open for recording and throws an error "SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE - Fatal Error"... Have u any idea how to resolve this issue? I am asking this issue from all of my LinkedIn contacts so is you :) Error screenshot have been attached with this email... Keep in mind we dont have internet access on machine where Jmeter & Bank app running, LAN runs Bank App only. Thankful if u can gimme idea. Pls see attached screenshot of SSL error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rH0G.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing JMeter's self-signed certificate into your browser. The certificate is being generated when you start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) in JMeter's "bin" folder, the file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt`.

See the following reference material:

- **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) documentation
- [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server)

Be aware that the certificate has limited life time span (7 days) so if you have already imported it make sure it's still valid.

---

If it doesn't help you can consider playing with `https.default.protocol` and `https.socket.protocols` properties or [importing your application certificate into JMeter's keystore](https://www.grim.se/guide/jre-cert)